# HP 175X Jet Direct and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hp-pavilion

I am attempting to set my HP Pavillion running Windows 7 to my HP Photosmart using a 175x HP Jetdirect and can not get any printing. Is the jet direct not compatible?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Error messages? Jobs stuck?

Comment: I'm having problems with Windows 7 and an HP Jetdirect 175x too. The printer is an HP LaserJet 1300. I have an HP desktop running Win7-64. Printing is balky. Sometimes it goes right through and other times it will hang in the print queue until I restart the job two or three times.

From my Dell mini (Win7-32), nothing prints at all. Every print job hangs in the queue with a status of "Error - Printing." Restarting the job does not help.

Comment: More details: The HP LaserJet 1150/1300 Setup program fails to detect the printer on the network on the Dell mini connecting over wireless. I can install it manually by creating the port etc, but it doesn't work once it's done. I can ping the JetDirect from the Dell mini over the wireless, so I know basic connectivity isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The printserver is compatible, but your printer is most likely not.  Edit your post to include the printer model and then we can look it up for you.
Or you can go to: [HP](http://welcome.hp.com/country/us/en/support.html) and find out for yourself...